# Can sweet lime and orange cause kidney stone?

Tags: fruits, kidney, kidney-stones

I eat two sweet lime or orange daily after lunch and dinner. I have been doing this since 3 years for 3-4 months during the season of these two fruits.

As we know these fruits are acidic, is it possible that the amount in which I am consuming these two particular fruits can cause kidney stone in near future?